# How can I get a list of Elasticsearch index names using the Elasticsearch-PHP client?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

I need a list of index names from Elasticsearch that match a certain pattern. Using Kibana I've no problem doing this, but I simply can't figure out how to do the same with the Elasticsearch-PHP client.

Example:

```
Trying to get indices matching the name pattern "*.foo.bar"
With Kibana: GET /_cat/indices/*.foo.bar
```

Does anyone know? I've found nothing on this in the Elasticsearch-PHP docs.

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out through trial and error.

The way to get a list of indices matching a pattern is:

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$indices = $client->cat()->indices(array('index' => '*.foo.bar'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [current docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/7.2/ElasticsearchPHP_Endpoints.html#Elasticsearch_Namespaces_CatNamespaceindices_indices) at the time of this response (7.2), you can find the documentation for the endpoint `GET /_cat/indices/` that you're looking for.

So you can get the indices with this code:

```php
$params = [
    // Example of another param
    'v' => true,
    // ...
    'index' => '*.foo.bar'
];

$indices = $client->cat()->indices($params);
```

The documentation doesn't explicitly states about the `index` param, but you can see how the index is set inside the `CatNamespace::indices()` method definition.

```php
public function indices(array $params = [])
{
    $index = $this->extractArgument($params, 'index');
    ...
    $endpoint->setIndex($index);
    ...
}
```